# Change format from htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have apache server with htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^test/\$([^/]+)/([^/]+\.php)$  test/$2?VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^test/([^/]+)/(.*)$  $1/$2 [L]
```

And I am trying to convert it for nginx server.
I cant figure out how to transfor virtual directory to correct format.
This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin.dev;
    root "/home/vagrant/admin";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;


    rewrite_log on;

    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?$1 last;
    }

    location /res_partners/ {
        rewrite ^res_partners/\$([^/]+)/([^/]+\.php)$  res_partners/$2?VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME=$1 last;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/admin.dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

   location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }   

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }   

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/admin.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/admin.dev.key;
}
```

Any help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first rule seems to rewrite `/test/$something/somescript.php` to `/test/somescript.php?VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME=$something` and these are literal `$` characters. Your `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` container already matches any URI that ends with `.php`. So the first rule can be placed at the top of that container:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  rewrite ^/test/\$([^/]+)/([^/]+\.php)$ /test/$2?VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME=$1&$args break;
  ...
}
```

The second rule seems to rewrite `/test/somedir/something` to `/somedir/something` (where `something` is not a php script).

This can be achieved with a prefix location:

```
location /test/ {
  rewrite ^/test/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2;
}
```